# Iterate through items on a given date within date range rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I kind of have the feeling this has been asked before, but I have been searching, but cannot come to a clear description.

I have a rails app that holds items that occur on a specific date (like birthdays). Now I would like to make a view that creates a table (or something else, divs are all right as well) that states a specified date once and then iterates over the related items one by one.

Items have a date field and are, of course, not related to a date in a separate table or something.

I can of course query the database for ~30 times (as I want a representation for one months worth of items), but I think it looks ugly and would be massively repetitive. I would like the outcome to look like this (consider it a table with two columns for the time being):

```
Jan/1 | jan1.item1.desc
      | jan1.item2.desc
      | jan1.item3.desc
Jan/2 | jan2.item1.desc
      | etc.
```

So I think I need to know two things: how to construct a correct query (but it could be that this is as simple as `Item.where("date > ? < ?", lower_bound, upper_bound))` and how to translate that into the view.

I have also thought about a hash with a key for each individual day and an array for the values, but I'd have to construct that like above(repetition) which I expect is not very elegant.

Using `GROUP BY` does not seem to get me anything different (apart from the grouping, of course, of the items) to work with than other queries. Just an array of objects, but I might do this wrong.

Sorry if it is a basic question. I am relatively new to the field (and programming in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making a calendar, you probably want to `GROUP BY` date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS instances, DATE(`date`) AS on_date FROM items GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

This is presuming your column is literally called `date`, which seeing as how that's a SQL reserved word, is probably a bad idea. You'll need to escape that whenever it's used if that's the case, using ``` here in MySQL notation. Postgres and others use a different approach.

For instances in a range, what you want is probably the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
@items = Item.where("`date` BETWEEN ? AND ?", lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

Comment: I am able to construct an SQL query using group, both with rails and through direct SQL. This gives me an array of objects on which I can call sensible methods (as given in de SQL query). But how would I translate that to a view? I can't seem to figure out what I could do to iterate through individual groups or something.

Comment: If you have objects, save them in an instance variable, as all instance variables are automatically available in views. You'd iterate in the view as you would any other array.

Comment: I know that, but the point for me is that I would like a single query, but an iteration for two layers (unless this is not necessary). I will update my question somewhat to make the objective more clear.

Comment: Instead of doing the grouping in the database, what about doing it with [`group_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) in your Rails app?

Comment: Hi tadman, took me a while to get back, but I have been fiddling tonight and you have definitely pointed me in the right direction. The `group_by` will help me out. I have collected some other input (railscasts, the API docks) to get the complete picture, but I'm getting there. Many thanks! (I learned a lot again!)